# Weakly bounded sets

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Then my book defines the set $A$ to be weakly bounded if $\sup_{a \in A}|f(a)| < \infty$ for all $f \in X^{\ast}$. I was thinking this should be somehow connected to the weak topology where the open sets are of the form $W(f_1, \dots ,f_n ;r)=\{x \in X : |f_i(x)| <r$ for all $ 1 \leq i \leq n\}$.

We also know that a space $A \subset X$ is bounded iff there exist some $M>0$ such that $A \subset M \mathcal{B}_{X}$. Where $\mathcal{B}_{X}=\{x \in X : \|x\| < M\}$. Thus i was thinging it would make sense if being weakly closed was equivalent too: There exixst some $M>0$ and $r>0$ such that $A \subset MW(f_1, \dots ,f_n ;r)$ i.e that $A$ is contained in some open set M with a "radius" r. However this seems to not be the case.

It is clear that if $A$ is weakly bounded then $A \subset W(f,C)$ where $C=\sup_{a \in A} |f(a)|$. However if we have that $A \subset W(f_1,\dots ,f_n ;r)$ for some $f_1, \dots, f_n \in X^*$ and $r>0$ I think this not neccesarily implies that A is weakly bounded as we only know that $\sup_{a \in A} |f(a)| < \infty$ for finetly many functionals.

So my question is: Why do we not have this realtion (or do we and in that case what is my misunderstanding?), and how can I instead se a realtion between weakly bounded and the weak topology?

Comment: Weakly bounded implies bounded in norm by identifying $A$ with $j(A)\subseteq X^{\ast\ast}$ and using Banach-Steinhaus, while $W(f_i,r)$ is always unbounded in norm, since it contains the finite intersection of the codimension $1$ kernels of the $f_i$

Answer (score 1):

In a general *topological vector space* $X$, a set $A\subset X$ is called *bounded* if, for *every* neighborhood $U\ni 0$ of the origin, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon A\subset U$. So your guess is correct. But you missed the *every* part. If for *every* basic open set $W(f_1, \dots ,f_n ;r)$,  there exists $\epsilon_{f_1,\cdots, f_n; r}>0$ such that $\epsilon_{f_1,\cdots, f_n; r} A\subset W(f_1, \dots ,f_n ;r)$. Then it's easy to see $\sup_{a\in A}|f(a)|<\infty$ for every $f\in X^*$.

Conversely if $\sup_{a\in A}|f(a)|<\infty$ for every $f\in X^*$, then for every basic open set $W(f_1, \dots ,f_n ;r)$, let
$$\epsilon_{f_1,\cdots, f_n; r}:=\frac{r}{\max\{\sup_{a\in A}|f_1(a)|, \cdots, \sup_{a\in A}|f_n(a)|\}}>0.$$
Then we have $\epsilon_{f_1,\cdots, f_n; r} A\subset W(f_1, \dots ,f_n ;r)$.